# Fragment asynchronous Interface callback handling

Tags: android, android-fragments, asynchronous

I have a `Fragment` that does some communication with the internet trough some helper `Class` that requires an interface to handle asynchronous callbacks like this:

```
SomeInternetCommunicator.getResource(theResourceToGet, retrieverInterfaceInstance);
```

The interface looks like this:

```
public interface SomeInternetCommunicator {
     void onResourceRetrieveSuccess(SomeResource resource);
     void onResourceRetrieveFailed(CommunicatorException e);
}
```

The problem is that, sometimes the calls take too long, the user already navigated elsewhere and the `Fragment` that did the call to `getResource` is not part of the currently running `Activity` anymore (not showing, not on backstack).  This causes many problems because this orphan `Fragment` is still attempting to react to the callbacks even if it is not part of the `Activity` anymore. For example, `getContext()` returns null.

Now my workaround on the `Fragment` looks like this:

```
SomeInternetCommunicator flocktrackerTrackerRetrieverInterface = new SomeInternetCommunicator() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceRetrieveSuccess(SomeResource resource) {
                if(isVisible()){
                    doRetrievalPostProcessing(resource);
                }
            }

            @Override
            void onResourceRetrieveFailed(CommunicatorException e) {
                if(isVisible()){
                    doExceptionHandling();
                }
            }
        };
```

Using the `isVisible()` works because this ensures that the fragment is still on the foreground, part of the `Activity` and ready to do the handling. This, however, doesn't help me to cover the case for when the `Fragment` is not visible, but still part of the current `Activity`, limiting my possibilities for loading the `Fragment` before showing it. (`Activity` is in the background, `Fragment` is on the `Backstack`, `Fragment` loaded by a `ViewPager`).

Is there a better way to ensure that the `Fragment` is still on the current `Activity`'s scope before I do the postprocessing? Maybe checking `isAdded()`?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208806/should-we-ever-execute-asynchronous-tasks-in-android-fragments) seems to explain a broader but related situation, but it has no answers.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes isAdded() is correct. If you want to have more action when it is added and removed, override onAttach() and onDetach().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there're two usual approaches to this case:

1. the best approach is to have a way to clear the interface instance from the `SomeInternetCommunicator`. Something like:

.

```
@Override public void onDestroyView(){
   SomeInternetCommunicator.removeMe(this);
}
```

2. if option (1) is not possible because `SomeInternetCommunicator` is a poorly coded library, you force option 1 to be possible by making a separate class to implement the interface.

.

```
public class SomeInternetCommunicatorInterceptor implements SomeInternetCommunicatorInterface {

    private SomeInternetCommunicatorInterface listener;

    public void setListener(SomeInternetCommunicatorInterface listener){
        this.listener=listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResourceRetrieveSuccess(SomeResource resource){
         if(listener != null){
              listener.onResourceRetrieveSuccess(resource);
         }
    }
    @Override
    public void onResourceRetrieveFailed(CommunicatorException e){
         if(listener != null){
              listener.onResourceRetrieveFailed(e);
         }
    }
}
```

then on your fragment you use this new class as:

```
private SomeInternetCommunicatorInterceptor interceptor;

public void onCreateView(....){

... your code

   interceptor = new SomeInternetCommunicatorInterceptor();

}

onStart(){
   interceptor.setListener(this);
}

onStop(){
   interceptor.setListener(null);
}

public void onDestroyView(){
   interceptor = null;
   super.onDestroyView();
}
```

**VERY IMPORTANT:**

if you make `SomeInternetCommunicatorInterceptor` an internal class of the fragment you HAVE TO make it as `static class`

Comment: Thanks!, SomeInternetCommunicator is a poorly coded library indeed, but it is coded by myself, so I can do the changes you suggest.

Comment: Using a similar approach, would it be possible to "cache" the event if the fragment is detached or the activity is destroyed, and use that event as soon as the activity is recreated/fragment is attached? For example, in my app I can perform a network request that in some cases can take some time. When there is a success or failure, I notify the user with a `Snackbar`, but this is not possible in case the activity got destroyed (back button, garbage collection, etc... ). To make up with the detached fragment, I have a `WeakReference` to the android.R.id.content `View` for the `Snackbar`. Thanks